# Python Pandas colour background cell if number equals

Tags: python, pandas, colors, background, background-color

I am currently able to change the background of a cell using the following code:

```
def my_func_blue(val):
    if val in techniques:
        color = 'green'
        return f'background-color: {color}'
    elif val in Fulltechniques:
        color = 'red'
        return f'background-color: {color}'
s = df1.style.applymap(my_func_blue)
s
```

I want to be able to add another IF statement into

```
"if val in techniques"
```

so if the occurrence is MORE THAN 1 it applies the colour:

DF:

```
Technique_Name  Technique_ID    SOC Alarm   Occurance
0   Sudo and Sudo Caching   T1548.003   002 1
1   Elevated Execution with Prompt  T1548.004   003 1
13  Cloud Account   T1087.004   015 2
14  Cloud Account   T1087.004   032 2
15  Account Manipulation    T1098   016 1
```

So only the cell which contains Cloud Account would have the background colour of Green

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If logic is more complicated is possible chain multiple conditions, e.g. here `m1` with `m2` for create Dataframe of styles and if necessary create excel file:

```
techniques = ['Cloud Account','Account Manipulation']
Fulltechniques = ['Sudo and Sudo Caching']

def my_func_blue(x): 
   c1 = 'background-color: green'
   c2 = 'background-color: red'
   c = ''
   m1 = x.Technique_Name.str.contains('|'.join(techniques))
   m2 = x.Technique_Name.str.contains('|'.join(Fulltechniques))
   m3 = x.Occurance.gt(1)

   df1 = pd.DataFrame(c, index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
   df1 = df1.mask(m1 & m3, c1).mask(m2, c2)
   return df1

(df.style.apply(my_func_blue,axis=None)
         .to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', index=False))
```

Comment: I've changed it for my variables but it appears to stop after the first match where I would need it to work its way through it all. E.G out of my list above only "Sudo and Sudo Caching" is matching as RED and thats all

Comment: @TiiTcHY - Can you check now? I change `isin` for [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for match all values of lists joined by `|` for regex `or`